# How to take binary encryption from this script

Tags: ruby

Hellom, me and my friends are creating an MMORPG, and the base that we're using have this script on database.rb.

I'm doing a registration system for the website, but I need to make the server and game create files without having binary in the middle of the reading.

```
def self.create_account(user, pass, email)
        registro = Binary_Writer.new
        registro.write_string(pass)
        registro.write_string(email)
        registro.write_byte(Constants::GROUP_STANDARD)
        # In that part, makes the save in binary.
        file = File.open("Data/Accounts/#{user}.bin", mode: 'wb')
        file.write(registro.to_s)
        file.close
    end
```

I tried to learn and find where i need to change to doesn't use binary, i think, that is in the part that i commented on script.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal for the code not to write to a `.bin` file?

Comment: Why are you writing to files in the first place? Why not a database?

Comment: Like @tadman said, if you’re making an MMORPG and not using databases then you’re doing it wrong in every way. If you don’t understand why then you’re woefully ill-equipped to undertake the task at all, and I would recommend studying how existing systems work (for months or years) before attempting a project like this.

Comment: Another thing to note here that's really important is, and I'm bolding for emphasis, **NEVER, EVER STORE USER PASSWORDS AS PLAIN TEXT**. Always, and I mean **always** use a password-specific hashing method like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), something that's available as a [Ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt/versions/3.1.12) and is really easy to use. If this data leaks out and it has plain-text passwords in it you're endangering your users. If you leak properly hashed passwords you at least protect people from password attacks.